# App does not start in simulator. Got error: No such process

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1, simulator

After app building and installing into simulator, app can not start. *Device: Macbook Pro 16, M1 Pro*. Other projects work correctly without this error.
Error description:

```
Application launch for '...' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-11-04 18:24:54 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue with one of my projects. It runs fine once, but if I run again on the same Simulator I get the same error. If I select a different Simulator, it runs ok again (once).

Comment: @MihaiL You can enable Rosetta. Go Applications folder, right click on xCode, Settigs/Options/Preferences and enable Run with Rosetta. This was my Solution

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know! It fixes it for me as well. But I wonder if we don't lose performance having Xcode not running natively on the M1.

Comment: im using flutter framework and facing the same problem, but Rosetta doesnt work in my case